# Create User Specific Objects in Django

Tags: python, django, object, models

Ive been trying to create a django project that has users and those users can add titles of books they have created. Only the user will be able to view the titles of his books. I was wondering how can I create a class in models.py, forms.py, & views.py that will tie the user and the titles of their books together. Here is what I have so far.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Scripter(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Title(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Scripter)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.script_title
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.forms import ModelForm
from scripters.models import Scripter, Title

class RegistrationForm(ModelForm):
    username = forms.CharField(label=(u'User Name'))
    email = forms.EmailField(label=(u'Email Address'))
    password = forms.CharField(label=(u'Password'), widget=forms.PasswordInput(render_value=False))
    password1 = forms.CharField(label=(u'Verify Password'), widget=forms.PasswordInput(render_value=False))

    class Meta:
        model = Scripter
        exclude = ('user',)

    def clean_username(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data['username']
        try:
            User.objects.get(username=username)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return username
        raise forms.ValidationError("User Name has been taken!")

    def clean(self):
        if self.cleaned_data['password'] != self.cleaned_data['password1']:
        raise forms.ValidationError("The passwords did not match")
        else:
            return self.cleaned_data

class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(label=(u'Username'))
    password = forms.CharField(label=(u'Password'), widget=forms.PasswordInput(render_value=False))

class CreateScript(ModelForm):
    title = forms.CharField(label=(u'Script Title'))

    class Meta:
        model = Title

    def clean_title(self):
        title = self.cleaned_data['title']
        return title
```

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from scripters.forms import RegistrationForm, LoginForm, CreateScript
from scripters.models import Scripter, Title
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout

def ScripterRegistration(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/')
    if request.method =='POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = User.objects.create_user(username=form.cleaned_data['username'],
                email = form.cleaned_data['email'],
                password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            )
            user.save()
            scripter = Scripter(user=user, name=form.cleaned_data['name'])
            scripter.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/')
        else:
            return render_to_response('index.html', {'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()
        context = {'form': form}
        return render_to_response('index.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

@login_required
def Profile(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/')
    Scripter = request.user.get_profile
    context = {'Scripter': Scripter}
    return render_to_response('profile.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def LoginRequest(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        submit = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if submit.is_valid():
            username = submit.cleaned_data['username']
            password = submit.cleaned_data['password']
            scripter = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if scripter is not None:
                login(request, scripter)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/')
            else:
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/')
    else:
        submit = LoginForm()
        context = {'submit': submit}
        return render_to_response('login.html',context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def LogoutRequest(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/')

@login_required
def NewScript(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/')
    if request.method =='POST':
        title_form = CreateScript(request.POST)
        if title_form.is_valid():
            title = User.objects.get_or_create(
                Title = title_form.cleaned_data['title'],
            )
            title.save()
            script = Title(script_title=title_form.cleaned_data['title'])
            script.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/edit/')
        else:
            return render_to_response('NewScript.html', {'title_form': title_form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        title_form = CreateScript()
        context = {'title_form': title_form}
        return render_to_response('NewScript.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: So... what did you need to do?

Comment: I want users to be able to add names of books they wrote, but only they can see them. Sort of like a online catalog. I already have the registration and login working, I just want a class that will tie the user and the books. So in essence when they logon they will click on "add book" which will redirect them to the form they will enter the name. And the book is added to their catalog.

Comment: Did you try providing an initial value for the user field, and excluding it from the form?

Comment: how would I do that. sorry I am a noob

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're asking is how do I get the list of titles that are owned by a specific user.

This is rather easy using a reverse relationship:

```
scripter.title_set.all()
```

Will get you all the books owned by an instance of Scripter.

Comment: This is helpful but how can they add new titles?

Comment: Just use 
scripter = Scripter.objects.get(pk=request.user) and then
Title.objects.create(author=scripter)

You can also use get_profile() for Scripter if you set it up right in your settings.